# SQL Join with partial string match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table 'TableA' like:

```
ID Group         Type       
1  AB            SomeValue 
2  BC            SomeValue
```

Another table 'TableB' like:

```
Product Subgroup             Type
A       XX-AB-XX-text        SomeValue
B       XX-BC-XY-text        SomeValue
```

I am using INNER JOIN between two tables like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM TableA TA
INNER JOIN TableB TB
ON TA.Type=TB.Type
```

I want to add another condition for join, which looks for value of 'Group' in 'Subgroup' and only joins if the 'Group' Value matches after 'XX-' and before '-XX'.

In other words, join only if Group 'AB' shows up at the correct place in Subgroup column.

How can I achieve this? I am using MSSQL

Comment: Doesn't that query raise a syntax error?

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, it's a set quantifier - and belongs to SELECT. Skip those extra parentheses and simply do `SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TableA ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT (DISTINCT ID) 
FROM TableA TA
INNER JOIN TableB TB
ON TA.Type=TB.Type AND TB.SubGroup LIKE '__-' + TA.Group + '%'
```

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question.  Won't __ match anything?  I thought he wanted to match ONLY XX- and -XX, and this expression doesn't address the -XX part of the problem.

Comment: Doesn't this query raise a syntax error?!?

Comment: The poster was looking for that position to match but I think not necessarily for it to have Xs before and after IE I took those to be placeholder values and not necessarily the actual values that will be there.

Comment: @jarlh what part of it do you think will raise an error? I don't have a copy of SQL Server so have not been able to test the original query

Comment: `SELECT (DISTINCT ID)` is very odd.

Comment: @jarlh agreed but I don't think there is a syntax issue with it

Comment: BTW, you can try your queries here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019

Answer (score 1):

You can use LIKE with CONCAT to build the expression, see this fiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d7bb4781488e53c31abce0f38d0aaef4

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA TA
JOIN TableB TB on (
  TA.types = TB.types AND
  TB.subgroup LIKE concat('XX-', TA.groups, '-XX%')
);
```

I am dumping all the returned data so you can see it, but you would want to modify that to return only DISTINCT TA.id.

It is possible to build the expression using + instead of CONCAT:

```
'XX-' + TA.groups + '-XX%'
```

Also, I would very strongly warn you against using column names that are reserved words.  Both GROUP and TYPE are in use by the SQL engine, so to use them you would have to escape them every time, and they might also cause confusion to anybody reading or maintaining your code.